# docopt usage not formatted correctly by sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docopt

Consider the following doc-string for *docopt*:

```
Usage:
    foo [options]
    foo [options] <input.yaml>

Options:
    -h, --help
        Show help.
```

when formatting with *Sphinx* the options are formatted very nicely (bold options, with regular, indented, description).

However, the usage is formatted poorly: everything is on a single line. My question: how can I format such that there is at least the line-break between the different use-cases, but in such a way that docopt is not broken? In particular, the following Sphinx solutions break *docopt*:

```
Usage:
|    foo [options]
|    foo [options] <input.yaml>
```

```
Usage:
    foo [options]

    foo [options] <input.yaml>
```

Comment: I think "Options" looks OK because it is interpreted as an option list (https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#option-lists). But the "Usage" part is not recognized as an option list or any other special reST construct.

Comment: @mzjn Thanks. Indeed. But how can I do its such that it is reST interpretable as well as docopt interpretable ?

Comment: I don't know. This issue seems related: https://github.com/docopt/docopt/issues/210

Comment: @mzjn The issue is indeed related. However, it seems without real solution. The `.. literalinclude` is not an option as I use `.. automodule::`. A suggestion implies putting `Usage::`, which does not work unless a newline is put which is however not accepted by  doctopt...